# Rotate image when hover over list dropdown and rotate back when mouse ot over

Tags: javascript, html, css

Short Summary:

Upon hovering over drop down list, I would like to also rotate the arrow that is next to the list item.

https://jsfiddle.net/v08gxczo/

Long summary:

I have a list of navbar items, in which it contains a dropdown that has a right-pointing svg.

Upon hovering the 'dropdown' item the color changes, and the dropdown stays upon as long as one is hovering. I would love to `transform: rotate(xdeg)` upon also hovering on and within this list, except I'm having a world of trouble trying to capture it. It looks a little something like this (snippit + fiddle):

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}
img {
  padding-left:10px;
}
li {
  margin: auto 20px;
}

ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5 s ease;
  display: none;
  background - color: #0c0c0c;
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li ul li {
  padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}

ul li:hover>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}


ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>item 1</a><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32213.svg" alt="right-arrow" style="height:10px"/>
    <ul>
      <li><a>child 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>child 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>child 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In specifics, the highlighting dropdown happens here:

```
ul li:hover>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

and I'm not sure how I would incorporate the hover over to keep the item rotated at the same time there is a hover over.

I attempted with this:

```
ul li:hover>ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

but reading that code, it only makes sense that it would rotate the list, I which it does.

The more I look at this the harder it is for me to understand how to do this in just CSS. Even in javascript, it seems like a pain (adding event listeners to the open list, and then hover over to add or remove the class when mouseout.

Perhaps there is a solution I can't see?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, but I don't get it. What you are really trying to do?

Comment: When you hover over the list item, I'm trying to rotate the image (while hovered over), and then back to normal once unhovered.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. But then why didn't you apply `CSS` to the `img` tag?

Comment: See I couldn't figure out a way to do that to only affect it when hovered under that dropdown list

Comment: Right. I see it now. I'm going to create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to make an effect for the `image` when you hover the `list`.
You can affect rotating the `image` when hovering like this instead of your attempt:

```
ul li:hover img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

It's a simple answer, since I don't know if this is exactly what you're trying to do. Please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If possible try to add js fiddle because I cannot understand what is the result you are getting with your current code. All i can say with the code you have provided is if you want to rotate the image on li hover then give rotete property on that img i.e

```
 { transform: rotate(10deg); 
}
```

Comment: I added a fiddle with some more details on the question details.

Comment: Yes, All you are doing is correct just need to use transform proper on img i.e your code should look like ```ul li:hover>ul img,
ul li ul:hover img {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}```